# Should I use "as" or "since" in the following case?

Tags: conjunctions, comparison

> An hour had passed since we entered the forest. It seemed endless.
>   Either that or we were walking in circles; which was probably the case,
>   **as/since** I was seeing the same trees over and over again.

Which one is the correct option?

Comment: Related question: [When are “because”, “since”,“for” and “as” interchangeable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/when-are-because-since-for-and-as-interchangeable)

Answer (score 1):

Since both [**as** and **since**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-because-or-since) can serve as *conjunctions* meaning **because**, I guess both options are correct. Both words are somewhat more formal than **because**.

According to a Cambridge Dictionary [page on as/because/since](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-because-or-since), one should prefer **because**, not **as** or **since**, in *question sentences* proposing a reason for something:

> Are you feeling unwell **because** you ate too much?

But this is clearly not your case.

Sometimes **as** can be ambiguous because one of its meanings is "at the same time that; while", but this is not your case either.